ffmpeg fails to convert several ts files into one mp3
I'm joining several .ts files into one .mp3 file like this:
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg'

const tsDest = 'dir/file.ts'
const mp3Dest = 'dir/file.mp3'

const ff = ffmpeg(urls[0])
urls.slice(1).map(url => ff.input(url))

ff.on('error', function (err) {
  logger.error('An error occurred: ' + err.message)
  reject(err)
})
.on('end', function () {
  return ffmpeg(tsDest)
    .videoCodec('libx264')
    .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
    .on('error', function (err) {
      logger.error('An error occurred: ', err)
      reject(err)
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      resolve(mp3Dest)
    })
    .save(mp3Dest)
}).mergeToFile(tsDest, dir)

In the first part I receive this error:
An error occurred: ffmpeg exited with code 228: size=     259KiB time=00:00:04.95 bitrate= 428.6kbits/s speed=58.1x    
Conversion failed!

I have no clue why this happens and how to fix it. I can't find a pattern that I can follow to know why this happens and how, it just happens sometimes and some other times it doesn't. I've tried to find a solution but I couldn't find anything or any bug similar to mine.
I've put this question in the library (https://github.com/damianociarla/node-ffmpeg/issues/101) too let's see if I can get some useful info from somewhere.
Thanks in advance!
